# Rotating divs shows on top of each other

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So I am pretty sure this is a quick fix but this is breaking my brain. Simple I have a custom built dashboard with multiple divs which has rotating data within them, However when the page refreshes the first time the data all loads to screen and displays on top of each other, which sucks.

[image: Here is an image of the issue.]

Here is my code CSS & one of the divs (The top one)

```
    .blended_grid {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1px 0 0 0;

}

.left_block_container {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    height: 850px;

}

.left_div_1 {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    padding: 1px 0 0 0;

}

#left_div_1_slideshow {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(43, 174, 168, 0.65);
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

And the HTML / PHP

```
<div class="blended_grid">

    <h1 style="font-family: Ubuntu; color: #2baea8; margin-left: 20px">ITIO PERFORMANCE DASHBOARD</h1>

    <div class="left_block_container">
        <div class="left_div_1" style="padding-top: 0px">
            <div id="left_div_1_slideshow">
                <div align="center">
                    <img src="images/elements/project.png" class="pull-left" alt="" height="100px" style="padding-left: 5px;">
                    <h6 style="font-size: 14px; color: #2baea8; font-weight: bold">Project Hours Total</h6>

                    <h1 style="font-size: 80px; color: #2baea8; font-weight: bold">
                        <div id="1">
                            <script>
                                $(document).ready(function () {
                                    setInterval(function () {
                                        $("#1").load("scripts/topdiv_1_stat1.php");
                                    }, 3000);
                                });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </h1>


                </div>

                <div align="center">
                    <img src="images/elements/project.png" class="pull-left" alt="" height="100px"
                         style="padding-left: 5px;">
                    <h6 style="font-size: 14px; color: #2baea8; font-weight: bold">Project Hours System Center</h6>

                    <h1 style="font-size: 80px; color: #2baea8; font-weight: bold">
                        <div id="2">
                            <script>
                                $(document).ready(function () {
                                    setInterval(function () {
                                        $("#2").load("scripts/topdiv_1_stat2.php");
                                    }, 3000);
                                });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </h1>


                </div>

                <div align="center">
                    <img src="images/elements/project.png" class="pull-left" alt="" height="100px"
                         style="padding-left: 5px;">
                    <h6 style="font-size: 14px; color: #2baea8; font-weight: bold">Project Hours Service Center</h6>

                    <h1 style="font-size: 80px; color: #2baea8; font-weight: bold">
                        <div id="3">
                            <script>
                                $(document).ready(function () {
                                    setInterval(function () {
                                        $("#3").load("scripts/topdiv_1_stat3.php");
                                    }, 3000);
                                });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </h1>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
<script>

    $("#left_div_1_slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function () {
        $('#left_div_1_slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#left_div_1_slideshow');
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: don't use floats for positioning, if you just need things to be next to each other, use inline block or if you want a column layout, then use flex.  If you use floats, you will need to learn all the hacks and nuances that go with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the html, for each `#left_div_1_slideshow` slide (except the first one) add `style="display:none"` to the outer div. In this way, only the first slide is visible before the javascript kicks in. By doing this, you effectively do what the first line of your js is doing, so that line can be removed.

```
<div id="left_div_1_slideshow">
    <div align="center">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <div align="center" style="display:none">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <div align="center" style="display:none">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```